# Visualizing Ricci scalar curvature

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, visualization, curvature

I am trying to learn more about Ricci scalar curvature. I am trying to get an image in my head of what scalar curvature actually represents about the curvature of a manifold. The most familiar image I have of a scalar giving me information about a space is a scalar field, like temperature. Is that the right way to think about scalar curvature? If not, how should one envision scalar curvature?

According to Wikipedia [here](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalar_curvature), scalar curvature can be characterized as a multiple of the average sectional curvatures at a point.

Comment: Perhaps something like this might be useful although it comes from the world of physics and GR , not the Ricci flow of Hamilton but it might be of interest. http://math.ucr.edu/home/baez/gr/ricci.weyl.html

Comment: @Alan That was cool. Question: why does the Ricci curvature tensor measure changes in the volume of a ball? Suppose we don't specify that our manifold has the structure of a ball. How can we know the Ricci tensor is applicable to that manifold? That is, is Ricci limited only to manifolds with the structure of a ball?

Comment: What do you mean by structure of a ball - since we are talking about manifolds every point has  neighbourhood which is a ball. And I should add that the curvature is defined locally - we assign the curvature at each point.

Comment: @JosephZambrano Where does it say that in the definition? I thought a smooth manifold was a topological manifold with a smooth structure. and that the only characteristics of a topological manifold are that its Hausdorff, second-countable, and with nbhd at each point homeomorphic to $\Bbb{R}^n$. It never usually says anything about a ball...

Comment: A ball is homeomorphic (diffeomorphic) to $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: So why does the definition of Ricci specify balls as opposed to any structure homeomorphic to $\Bbb{R}^{n}$?

Comment: Note that scalar curvature is not the same as Ricci curvature. Both measure infinitesimal volume growth but in different fashion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For 2D manifolds the scalar curvature is the Gauss curvature. Positive means the manifold closes in on itself, negative means it spreads out like a saddle.

*Some* of this parallel remains in higher dimensions, since the sign of curvature determines the asymptotic volume comparison for geodesic balls (positive curvature $\implies$ less-than -Euclidean volume, negative $\implies$ greater than Euclidean). However this is on small scale only, and therein lies a problem: the scalar curvature does not deliver much global geometric information.

Indeed, the [asymptotic volume definition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalar_curvature#Direct_geometric_interpretation) implies that scalar curvature is additive under products. Thus, by taking product with a sufficiently scaled-down compact surface of constant negative  curvature (think of a tiny double torus), we can make scalar curvature negative, as long as it was bounded to begin with.  And by taking product with a tiny sphere, the scalar curvature can be made positive.

These examples explain why there isn't a picture of what a manifold of positive/negative scalar curvature looks like: it can look like pretty much anything. (There are some obstructions to manifolds admitting positive scalar curvature, but they are not  easy to visualize.)

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. Thanks. Question: what is a geodesic ball?

Comment: The set of all points at distance less than $r$ from the center. The distance on a Riemannian manifold is the length of shortest geodesic, hence the name.

Comment: @Fundamental: Actually, in dimensions $>2$ there are no obstructions for a manifold to have a metric of negative Ricci curvature. For positive scalar curvature, of course, there are many restrictions and none of them simple indeed...